# R: how to find elements in one column based on combined conditions in other columns

Tags: r

I am trying to find the corresponding element in the column ID based on a combined condition if the column GROUP equals to 2 and the maximum value occurr in the column OBS.

How to do this task in R?

Here is my dataset:

```
ID <- as.factor(c("A","B","C","D","E","F"))
OBS <- c(1,3,2,8,3,10)
GROUP <- as.factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,2))     
df <- data.frame(ID,OBS,GROUP)
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what did you try? to be clear, you want the max  OBS out of the total data set or only the max of the GROUP==2?

Comment: For the latter... `by(df, df$GROUP, function(x) x[which.max(x$OBS), ] )$\`2\`` but don't do that.

Comment: From the example, the maximum value in OBS is 10 for GROUP 2. And, the corresponding element in ID is F.  I want to find the corresponding element based on GROUP and the maximum OBS.

Comment: I don't know what's stopping you. You can probably guess that R has functions with names like `==` and `max`...

Comment: I do not know the function which.max ...

Comment: Yes. I want to find the max OBS of the GROUP==2 and then allocate the corresponding element in ID.

Comment: You don't actually need which.max. I meant like Audiophile's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you mean that you want to first subset the data frame by the condition that `GROUP` should be equal to 2, and then identify the ID for which the value of `OBS` is highest, this should do the trick:

```
df2 <- df[df$GROUP==2,]
df2$ID[df2$OBS==max(df2$OBS)]
```

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning easier syntax with packages: `library(data.table); setDT(df)[ GROUP==2 ][ OBS == max(OBS) ]` or `library(dplyr); df %>% filter(GROUP == 2) %>% filter(OBS == max(OBS))`

Comment: `with(df, ID[which.max(OBS * GROUP %in% 2)])` I also did it in 0 lines, but I'm not telling you how

Comment: 0 lines? by eyes? : )